# How to compare 2 csv files, perform operations and output into a new csv file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, pattern-matching

I don't have any idea on how to compare 2 csv files (old.csv, change.csv) and after performing different operations (add, update,delete) a new.csv file will produce. I just need an Idea on how to do this. I was able to read and write a file using FileReader and Writer. I don't know how to compare files and perform operations. I should use an array for data-entries.

My csv files contains column:

```
Old.csv
CODE  NAME  ADDRESS  NUMBER
0001  John  USA      1234

Change.csv
CHANGE  CODE  NAME   ADDRESS  NUMBER
ADD     0002  Shane  Germany  5678
UPDATE  0001         Canada   

New.csv
CODE   NAME  ADDRESS  NUMBER
0001   John  Canada   1234
0002   Shane Germany  5678
```

Please help for ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you decide on the file-structure yourself? If so then I would suggest you add an ID to identify the dataset. Otherwise you will run into an issue as soon as you have the same name twice. Or is that what number column is inteded for? Have you considered importing the csv into a MySQL database? This way you could work with SQL-Language to change the data-entries

Comment: Primary key is the CODENUMBER. Sorry I forgot to add. I shouldnt use SQL instead array for data entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a task i suggest to use a csv parser like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [supercsv](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html)

and make use of a data class.

Below is an example using opencsv:

Create a class which looks something like this:

```
    public class Person {

    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String number;

    public Person(String code, String name, String address, String number) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.number = number;            
    }

    public String geCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

and use above class as data holder in your application to compare the two files and create a new csv file

```
    import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String oldFile = "Old.csv";
            String changeFile = "Change.csv";
            String newFile = "New.csv";
            Map<String,Person> personsList = readOldCsv(oldFile);
            personsList = getChangesfromChangeCsv(changeFile,personsList);
            writeNewCsvFile(newFile,personsList);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //read your old csv file line by line and create an object person 
    //and put it in a map with code as key and person itself as value
    //here assumed that your files are tab separeted '\t'; 
    //if not change to ';' or ',' according to your separator
    public static Map<String,Person> readOldCsv(String fileName) throws IOException{
        Map<String,Person> personsList = new HashMap<>();
        String [] nextLine;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '\t' ,'\'', 1);
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {        
            personsList.put(nextLine[0],new Person(nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3]));
        }       
        return personsList;        
    }
    // read your change csv file and add or update persons depending on the change column
    public static Map<String,Person> getChangesfromChangeCsv(String fileName, Map<String,Person> personsList) throws IOException{            
        String [] nextLine;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '\t' ,'\'', 1);
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) { 
            switch(nextLine[0].toLowerCase()){
                case "add":
                    personsList.put(nextLine[1],new Person(nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3], nextLine[4]));
                case "update":
                    personsList.get(nextLine[1]).setName(!nextLine[2].isEmpty()? nextLine[2]:personsList.get(nextLine[1]).getName());
                    personsList.get(nextLine[1]).setAddress(!nextLine[3].isEmpty()? nextLine[3]:personsList.get(nextLine[1]).getAddress());
                    personsList.get(nextLine[1]).setNumber(!nextLine[4].isEmpty()? nextLine[4]:personsList.get(nextLine[1]).getNumber());
                default:
                    System.out.println("unexpected entry");
            }                
        } 
        // use TreeMap to get a map sorted by key
        return new TreeMap<>(personsList);        
    }

    //write the values of the map into a new csv file
    private static void writeNewCsvFile(String filename,Map<String,Person> personsList) throws IOException {            
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename,false), '\t',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
        for(Person p : personsList.values() ){
            String[] entries = {p.geCode(),p.getName(),p.getAddress(),p.getNumber()};
            writer.writeNext(entries);
        }                
        writer.close();                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright! I will use this. Thank you very much! I finally enlighten :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, here your name column is the primary key between 2 csv files, while reading the CSV file you can create a hashmap of  type, where Name=Name coulmn value and Data is the whole object. later while traversing each change CSV record you can have switch statement to handle change and in each case you can manage individual updates to hashmap. After successful traversal your hashmap would contain required updated instance, which you can traverse and covert to new csv.